# Using ArcPy search cursor to relate .csv and .shp

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, csv, cursor, relates

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1.

I'm trying to write a script that relates data from a .csv file to a utility pole shape file. Basically, we want the script to iterate through the pole # fields in each table and determine which pole numbers are missing from the .shp. Right now, the script iterates through every row of the field and appears to not be reading the pole # value inputted by the user, since every print out reads the pole # and NO (ex: 111A0111, NO) no matter if the pole # is matching or not. We want the program to read "YES" if the pole number is in both tables, and "NO" if it is only in the .csv file and not the .shp.

```
import arcpy
import csv


#define other variable
fc = "P:\Scripts\data_check\prd_poles.shp"
field = "GISID"

#Create a list to be populated by the search shapefile search cursor
gis_poles_assets =[]

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

#Populate the list
for row in cursor:
  gis_poles_assets.append(row.getValue(field))
#print gis_poles_assets


#define the csv to be read by the reader and make that a variable
f = open(r'P:\Scripts\data_check\discoverer_poles_snip.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

#search the shapefile based on fields in a .csv
for row in csv_f:
  if row [1] in gis_poles_assets:
   pass
  elif "111A0111" in gis_poles_assets:
    print row [1], "YES"
    
  else:
    print row [1], "NO"
```

Comment: We've got 10.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. It uses a pandas dataframe with the newer da.SearchCursor.

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(r"path", usecols = ["GISID"]) 
fc = r".shp"
fields = ['GISID']

gis_poles_assets =[]



with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        gis_poles_assets.append(row[0])


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if not row['GISID'] in gis_poles_assets:
        print row['GISID'] + " No"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the old cursor which is much slower than the data access cursor. Create a view of the csv and use cursors on both shape and view to list all values then compare using sets:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\ak_riks'
fcfield = 'polenr'
poles_in_fc = [f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fcfield)]

csv = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\plist.csv'
csvfield = 'polenr'
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table=csv, out_view='csvview')
poles_in_csv = [f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('csvview',csvfield)]

print 'Poles in csv but not in fc: {}'.format(list(set(poles_in_csv)-set(poles_in_fc))) #https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-difference/
```

[image]